# EntityFramework 6.1.3 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I build I get an error that reads:

**EntityFramework 6.1.3 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0**

I have researched this issue and understand that the problem lies in the project.json.

However implementing other people's solutions in my app has not worked. Any help would be great. Thanks

project.json

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use EF Core for .NET Core, otherwise use Desktop CLR for your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 is designed to work with .NET Framework. For .Net Core you should use Entity Framework Core which is at version 1.1.

Here is a link to Microsoft Docs where you can see a comparison of the two: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/index

Comment: Will not make that mistake again moving forward. I appreciate the insight!